# How to display the fetched from DB to HTML Page using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, json

Im using jquery for a sample http get request to fetch the json from the DB. When I executed the get request I got the json array from DB. Also Im trying to display the json in the html page, so I used the jquery `$(newData).html(data)` to display the json. But Im not able to see the json in the html page, also the words inside the `<span>` tag disappear, I feel its trying to display the whole json but it is not seen on the page, so need help in displaying the json data in the page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Http Get Method</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $.get("http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json",function(data, status){

                        $("#newData").html(data);

                });
            });
        });

    </script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="getMethod.css"/> -->
</head>
<body>
<button> Get </button>
<span id="newData">
DISPLAY THE RESULT
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please create a working example, so I can help you accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data as below mentioned.

```
var data = '{"id": 1,"name": "test"}';
var json = JSON.parse(data);
alert(json["name"]);
alert(json.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text `DISPLAY THE RESULT` is disappearing because you are using `.html` which sets the content of that selected query, i.e. it replaces any data if there was any.

Therefore you should use `.append()` function instead which append to the existing data in the selected query.

you forgot that the data you are getting is in JSON format and you won't be able to append it directly to the page, generally you would like to display in table format or something  similar, anyway just to display the data you are getting directly use `data = JSON.stringify(data)` before you append it to the html page.

Replace the line

`$("#newData").html(data);`

with

`$("#newData").append(JSON.stringify(data));`

Answer (score 0):

Please try my solution and let me.. By using jsonp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Http Get Method</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        
             $("button").click(function(){
                   $.ajax({
                      url: "http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json",
                      type: "GET",
                      dataType: 'jsonp',
                      success: function (data, status, error) {
                          console.log(data);
                          data = JSON.stringify(data);
                          $("#newData").html(data);
                      },
                      error: function (data, status, error) {
                          console.log('error', data, status, error);
                          data = JSON.stringify(data);
                          $("#newData").html(data);
                      }
                 });
             });
        });

    </script>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="getMethod.css"/> -->
</head>
<body>
<button> Get </button>
<span id="newData">
DISPLAY THE RESULT
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This error is coming for you because stackoverflow refuses to load other url data from its console, though it will work fine from the local machine